# Sending notifications to a HTML5 App in Android/iOS

Tags: html, push-notification, hybrid-mobile-app, html5-apps

Is it possible to send real-time notifications to a Android/iOS device (from server) running an HTML5 App? How is it different from native apps? What extra efforts do I need to make for that?

Comment: It is not clear if you mean a notification from server to the app or from the app to the operative system (android notification).

Comment: For the first one, I would think of WebSocket, for the second one, PhoneGap indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify your server-side technology stack.

If however you are using Phonegap for the HTML5 App and node.js for the server, you have the option to use:

- node-gcm for sending notifications from your server
- PushPlugin for handling notifications from within your html5 app.

Both are explained at this post:

http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/